# Missing output when redirecting STDOUT to file

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, cmd, dos

I have a batch file in which I'm executing my c++ application.

The execution is something like

```
program.exe arguments >log.log 2>&1
```

It runs fine, but there is logging that is missing from the log file AND the cmd window. When I remove the redirection, the missing logs *are* in the cmd execution window. Also, if I run the program in Visual Studio, there is no missing output in the execution window.

The messages that I notice are missing in this case are simple printf() statements, but I suspect there may be other messages missing too (it's a large enterprise system).

This seems pretty bizarre, any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: printf(), ">" and (equivalently) "1>" write only to STDOUT.  It sounds like you're missing "STDERR"?  SUGGESTIONS: 1) try this syntax: `dir > a.txt 2>&1` (don't use "1>"), 2) specify exactly where you're doing the redirection; which command shell you're using (a CMD prompt?  A "system()" call?  Something else?)

Comment: is the write buffer being flushed regularly? (i.e. fflush() is invoked at some point?)

Comment: @paulsm4: I actually was originally was using ">", not "1>", I just tried both and the later is the one that ended up in my paste.
I'm using a CMD.exe prompt.

Comment: @Dataknife: My prints are ending with \n, doesn't that flush? And why would redirecting stdout change this behavior?

Comment: '\n' does not flush. You are looking for fflush().

Comment: Can you post a minimal porgram and inputs and command line the reproduces the behaviour?

Comment: So why does it flush without fflush() when the output is not redirected?

Answer (score 1):

Dataknife, was right. I added

> fflush(stdout);

and the output is showing up in the directed output.

Thanks!